# Как применить blur отдельно к каждому url() в background CSS?

Tags: html, css

Как применить blur к div с несколькими url в атрибуте background-image?

```
background: url(img_flwr.gif) right bottom no-repeat, url(paper.gif) left top repeat;
```

Такой бы вариант, но рабочий ;)

```
filter: blur(6px), blur(3px);
```

Comment: Такое возможно только для разных блоков с разными фонами.

Answer (score 0):

5 минут вопросов яндексу и вот отсюда: https://habr.com/ru/post/264037/
появляется такая конструкция:

```
.element {
    background: filter(url(path/to/img.jpg), blur(5px)), filter(url(path/to/img.jpg), blur(2px));
}
```